# Email with multiple categories is not grouped properly

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

*I hope this is the correct exchange for this question, if not please let me know a better one*

We use an Exchange 2013 mailbox with several people.

Most of them (including me) use Mac and don't have the problem. Now a colleague has the following problem, but she cannot remember whether it has always been like this or whether it is new. She says it used to be different.

We categorize emails with the categories. If you then sort by category at the top, all emails with the same category are shown together. For example, if an email has category A and B, it will be grouped as A, B

On a Mac it looks like this:
[image: How it looks on mac]
Now my colleague on Windows has the problem that only one category can be seen in the overview with all emails (same email):
[image: Windows overview]

If you then click on the email, however, you will see the other categories:
[image: Windows click on email]
Is this a bug or is something wrong set up? I have already removed the mailbox completely from the computer and added it again. Unfortunately without success.

So how do I make it so that all categories of an email are shown again in the overall overview with all emails?

Thanks very much!

Outlook Version: Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I can fully understand your case, for messages that originally had multiple categories, only the category of that category group are displayed. But all categories are displayed when you preview the message on the right or double-click to open the message, right?

[image]

If so, i'm afraid that it's by design and the condition is the same in different Outlook for windows desktop client. If you indeed need this feature, It is recommended that you could post the functions you expect and your suggestions on the [website](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) dedicated to collecting feedback.

---

Based on my test in my Outlook 2016, the email with two categories(green and yellow) can be grouped in green group and yellow group.

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

> Now my colleague on Windows has the problem that only one category can be seen in the overview with all emails (same email)

Does this issue occur with only the specific email with two categories? Please add two categories to other emails to check if they can be sort as several category group.

In addition, have you change other view settings? It's suggested that you could click Reset View via View>Current View group to check if there're any differences.

If the above doesn't help, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Thank you! I've added the outlook version to the question. Although none of the above worked, I found something strange. After I've reset the view, the sorting was resetted to date received. When I sort with "Date received" I see multiple categories on email. When I click on categories in the top bar for sorting, only one is shown. This happens to all emails, also a new test with a brand new email has this problem. I tried to look into the sorting settings but couldn't find anything in there that was helping.

Comment: I tested on a completely different machine now. Still problem as described in my comment. Because I never use outlook on windows I can't verify it this was working before in any case. I can only "trust" the word of my co worker. Not sure if she even ever sorted for category before... Any idea if this is still possible to achieve? Show all categories when sorting for category?

Comment: Hi @jona! I have updated my reply above.  If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer, which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.